# D3DXLoadSurfaceFromResourceW and D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFileW equivalents in DX11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directx-9

I need to remove dependency on d3dx(d3dx9tex.h) and port my application to DX11 APIs. I have looked at [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), but am unable to find equivalent functions for 
[D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFileW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3dxloadsurfacefromfile) and [D3DXLoadSurfaceFromResourceW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3dxloadsurfacefromfile) in DX11.

What is equivalent of these functions in DX11?

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you are doing with those functions, but a number of replacements are spelled out [in this blog post](https://aka.ms/Kfsdiu)